# Install ubuntu(msata) alongside win8(hard disk)

Tags: windows-8, ssd, ubuntu-14.04

I have a lenovo Y400. I have installed a 256 gb ssd drive on the empty mSata port.
I would like to install ubuntu 14 on the ssd and keep Windows 8 intact on the hard drive.

I would like to see Ubuntu and windows 8 in my boot menu.

I am not sure about the implications on the boot sector because of UEFI.

Could someone tell me the steps I need to follow?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends if your mSata is ranked before your actual hard drive. Doing so will make things much easier afterwards.

If you can change the boot order to priorize the mSata drive in your Bios, and just just simply install ubuntu normally. Note that the master boot record must be installed on the mSata drive.

This will not affect at all your windows drive, since the grub in your mSata will chainload your Windows Bootloader.